# 3ds format reading\writing

Tags: c++, 3ds

I am working on a program written in c++ that generates certain 3d objects based on user input. These objects contain a set of indexed vertices, normals, texture coordinates, position matrix and texture itself.

I need to export these objects to 3ds format however I cannot find any good info on how to do it. I've looked up libraries like assimp that work with 3d file formats but could not find ones that allow 3ds exporting. Format itself apparently isn't open so there are no documentations out there(at least none that I could find). There are some code snippets that read 3ds objects but they are 10 years old.

Is there a library that can handle 3ds export that I'm not aware of? Or maybe someone here had the same problem and could share their experience? The best course of action I see is finding some simple 3ds files and trying to reverse-engineer them but it seems suboptimal at best and could take tons of time.

Comment: Personally, I would output to FBX (using autodesk's sdk) and use some external tool to convert from fbx to 3ds (like running a simple blender script in headless mode)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Is there a reason you need 3DSMax's format specifically, or could you export to FBX say, then import that to Max?